# How to create color selector with Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport

The purpose is sliding the card and want to change the color of Card with color palette as in the picture below and below RecyclerView. What approach should I use?

[image: ColorSelector]

I have used this RecyclerView ItemDecoration but this is totally not fitting the design I want.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class LinePagerIndicatorDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final float DP = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    /**
     * Height of the space the indicator takes up at the bottom of the view.
     */
    private final int mIndicatorHeight = (int) (DP * 20);
    /**
     * Indicator stroke width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorStrokeWidth = DP * 16;
    /**
     * Indicator width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 2;
    /**
     * Padding between indicators.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemPadding = DP * 20;
    /**
     * Some more natural animation interpolation
     */
    private final Interpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private int[] colorActive = {0xFF9C27B0, 0xFF5C6BC0, 0xFF1E88E5, 0xFF3891FF, 0xFF00BCD4};
    private int[] colorInactive = {0x4D9C27B0, 0x4D5C6BC0, 0x4D1E88E5, 0x4D3891FF, 0x4D00BCD4};

    public LinePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mIndicatorStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
        float totalLength = mIndicatorItemLength * itemCount;
        float paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * mIndicatorItemPadding;
        float indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems;
        float indicatorStartX = (parent.getWidth() - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2F;

        // center vertically in the allotted space
        float indicatorPosY = parent.getHeight() - mIndicatorHeight / 2F;


        // find active page (which should be highlighted)
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
        int activePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        drawInactiveIndicators(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount, activePosition);
        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }

        // find offset of active page (if the user is scrolling)
        final View activeChild = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(activePosition);
        int left = activeChild.getLeft();
        int width = activeChild.getWidth();

        // on swipe the active item will be positioned from [-width, 0]
        // interpolate offset for smooth animation
        float progress = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(left * -1 / (float) width);
        drawHighlights(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition, progress, itemCount, activePosition);
    }

    private void drawInactiveIndicators(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY, int itemCount, int activePosition) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorInactive[activePosition]);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        float start = indicatorStartX;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            // draw the line for every item
            c.drawLine(start, indicatorPosY, start + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            start += itemWidth;
        }
    }

    private void drawHighlights(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY,
                                int highlightPosition, float progress, int itemCount, int activePosition) {

        mPaint.setColor(colorActive[activePosition]);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        if (progress == 0F) {
            // no swipe, draw a normal indicator
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,
                    highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
        } else {
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            // calculate partial highlight
            float partialLength = mIndicatorItemLength * progress;

            // draw the cut off highlight
            c.drawLine(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY,
                    highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);

            // draw the highlight overlapping to the next item as well
//            if (highlightPosition < itemCount - 1) {
//                highlightStart += itemWidth;
//                c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,
//                        highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
//            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = mIndicatorHeight;
    }
}
```

It produces this view which I don't want the color palette looking like this.

[image]